# Remove specific numbers from text using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of subtitles that has extra numbers that I want to get rid of.

```
0
00:00:00,262 -->00:00:30,670
<font>ﻊﻗﻮﻤﺑ ﺔﻴﺑﺮﻌﻟﺍ ﻞﻳﺪﻌﺗ ﻢﺗ</font>
<font>http://arabic-subtitles-fix.com</font>

1
00:00:06,693 --> 00:00:40,161
<font>ﺡﺍﺪﻘﻟﺍ ﺔﻓﺮﻃ ﺔﻤﺟﺮﺗ</font>
<font>alkadah@gmail.com</font>
<font>(ﺖﻴﻗﻮﺘﻟﺍ ﻞﻳﺪﻌﺗ)</font>
<font>ahmtie </font>
```

you see those numbers 0, 1, etc...
I want to get rid of those number because they're showing up on my TV.
Now I tried using notepad++ replace regular expression but, it's removing the all the numbers. I know there's a code that does it, but I can't thing of one. please help

Comment: As simple as `^\d+$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex needs to specify that digits are the only thing on the line.

Try `^\d*$`

Comment: You might want to match the carriage return and line feed characters too (e.g., `^\d+\r\n`)

Comment: @jbaums: yes, but in this case you must make it optional (for the last line): `^\d+(?:\r?\n|$)`

Comment: @Casimir Good point in general, but here I think it's safe to assume that the targets won't occur on the last line.

Comment: `\d` will also (as I understand it) get rid of any arabic numeric characters too (which may or may not be desirable)

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon: I don't think it is a problem since arabic characters seem to be embed inside font tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what language you're using to do this but you could always break up the text by line and then read back each line that is not digits. A PHP example could be;

```
$lines = explode("\n", $yourtext);
$finalLines = array();
foreach ($lines as $line)
  if (pre_match(/^\d*$/, $line))
    array_push($finalLines, $line);

implode("\n", $finalLines);
```

Maybe?